# packed structure size in C, is this correct?

Tags: packed

I found it in some exsiting code, it looks some problems, but the code works fine, can you help if this piece of code has any tricking things in.

why ignore two unsigned when calculate the size of the structure?

```
        tmsg_sz = sizeof(plfm_xml_header_t) + sizeof(oid_t) + sizeof(char*)
            + sizeof(unsigned) + sizeof(snmp_varbind_t)*5 ;
        tmsg = (snmp_trap_t*) malloc(tmsg_sz);
        if (!tmsg) {
            PRINTF("malloc failed \n");
            free(trap_msg);
            return -1;
        }
        memset (tmsg, 0, tmsg_sz);
        tmsg->hdr.type = PLFM_SNMPTRAP_MSG;
        copy_oid_oidt(clog_msg_gen_notif_oid, OID_LENGTH(clog_msg_gen_notif_oid), &tmsg->oid);
        tmsg->trap_type = SNMP_TRAP_ENTERPRISESPECIFIC;
        tmsg->trap_specific = 1;
        tmsg->trapmsg = strdup("Trap Message");
        tmsg->numofvar = 5;
        build_snmp_varbind(&(tmsg->vars[0]), facility, STR_DATA_TYPE, sizeof(facility)+1, clog_hist_facility_oid, 14);

        build_snmp_varbind(&(tmsg->vars[1]), &sev, U32_DATA_TYPE, sizeof(sev),clog_hist_severity_oid, 14);

        build_snmp_varbind(&(tmsg->vars[2]), name, STR_DATA_TYPE, sizeof(name)+1, clog_hist_msgname_oid, 14);

        build_snmp_varbind(&(tmsg->vars[3]), trap_msg, STR_DATA_TYPE, strlen(trap_msg)+1,clog_hist_msgtext_oid, 14);

        // get system uptime
        long uptime = get_uptime();
        build_snmp_varbind(&(tmsg->vars[4]), (long*)&uptime, TMR_DATA_TYPE, sizeof(uptime),clog_hist_timestamp_oid, 14);  



  typedef struct snmp_trap_s {
      plfm_xml_header_t hdr;
      oid_t             oid;        /* trap oid */
      unsigned          trap_type;
      unsigned          trap_specific;
      char              *trapmsg;   /* text message for this trap */
      unsigned          numofvar;
      snmp_varbind_t    vars[0];
  } __attribute__((__packed__)) snmp_trap_t;
```

Comment: "why ignore two unsigned when calculate the size of the structure?"
Huh?

Comment: @Judeyou This is one way to pack a data structure.  Looks like this is for gcc.  Other compilers use #pragma pack(1), for example.  What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: This looks odd to me.  I would have thought that the size would have been calculated as `sizeof(snmp_trap_s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers try hard to put multibyte data aligned in various ways.  For example, an `int` variable, in an architecture where `sizeof int == 4`, may need to be placed in a location divisible by `4`. This may be a hard requirement, or this may just make the system more efficient; it depends on the computer.  So, consider

```
typedef struct combo {
    char c;
    int  i;
} combo;
```

Depending on the architecture, `sizeof combo` may be 5, 6, or most often 8. Swap the two members, and the size should be 5.

```
typedef struct combo2 {
    int  i;
    char c;
} combo2;
```

However, an array of `combo2`s may have a size you do not expect:

```
combo2 cb[2];
```

The size of `cb` could very well be 16, as 3 bytes of wasted space follow `combo2[0]` and `combo2[1]`.  This lets `combo2[1].i` start at a location divisible by 4.

A recommendation is to order the members of a structure by size; the 8-byte members should precede the 4-byte members, then the 2-byte members, then the 1-byte members.  Of course, you have to be aware of typical sizes, and you can't be working on an oddball architecture where characters are not packed into larger words.  Cray? *cough-cough*.

Comment: @Peter L. I mean the size of the structure, why the 2 unsigned can be omitted in the calculating.